# Desabilitar armazenamento local de dados no meu site

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet

Tenho um site em que eu tenho uma base de usuários onde o software disponibilizado é atualizado diariamente. Quando o software atualiza o site também atualiza.

Só que, devido aos navegadores armazenarem dados muitas vezes o site atualizado não atualiza, oque ocorre o problema em que o link é desatualizado.

A tentei utilizar o [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
window.localStorage = false;
delete window.localStorage;
```

alguma sugestão?

Edit 1 : uma coisa interessante é. na parte onde o não é utilizado o ajax.load quando eu recarrego a pagina com ctrl shift r ela atualiza, mas as partes onde tem o ajax.load não...

Comment: O problema é relacionado aos ajax.load?

Comment: pode ser não sei ao certo.

Comment: Vc disse que algumas partes usam ajax.load... as partes que não atualizam estão sendo puxadas nesses ajax.load ou não necessariamente?

Comment: as partes que estão usando o ajax.load() não sao atualizadas mas uma coisa interessante é. na parte onde o não é utilizado o ajax.load quando eu recarrego a pagina com ctrl shift r ela atualiza, mas as partes onde tem o ajax.load não...

Comment: Tenta o seguinte: na url da página no ajax.load, coloque um parâmetro com um número randômico que é gerado cada vez que a página é carregada

Comment: Ja tive problema com requests em cache com o `service-worker.js`. Ja tentou importar esses javascripts adicionando no final da rota `?now={{ date.now }}`

Comment: tentei fazer os 2 jeitos, usando o date.now e fazendo um math random. os resultados foram , na primeira vez que recarrego com ctrl shift r ele recarrega normal e carrega os numeros aleatorios, mas depois da primeira vez qualquer hora que eu recarregar com o f5 ele não carrega o script